# Select and delete form controls without using the mouse in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I have some 0px width checkboxes in my Excel 2010 document and I can not select them by mouse. I need to delete them.

Is there a way to select them not using the mouse? Is there some list of all used form controls in a sheet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the 'Selection Pane'. Very handy.

Home Tab > Find & Select > Selection Pane

There you can show/hide/multiselect and also delete objects.

Support links:
[Microsoft: Select a shape or other object](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/select-a-shape-or-other-object-8db4e2f6-873a-46a7-87cb-fbb998a1f955?ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
[Microsoft: Manage objects with the Selection Pane](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-objects-with-the-selection-pane-a6b2fd3e-d769-46c1-9b9c-b94e04a72550?ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)